# Proposition involving inner product and derivatives

Tags: derivatives, inner-products, function-and-relation-composition

I've found this proposition and I don't know how to prove it. The proposition is the following:

Let's have $f:U\subset E\rightarrow R^{n}$, $E$ normed, $U$ open in $E$. Let's pick $p,q \in U, [p,q] \in U$ and $v\in R^{n}$ arbitrary. Then $\exists \space \xi \in [p,q]$ such that $\langle v,f(p)-f(q)\rangle=\langle v, Df_{\xi}(p-q)\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or course we need to assume that $f$ is differentiable. Define $g(t)=\langle v, f\bigl(tp+(1-t)q\bigr) \rangle$. Then $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable, so by [Lagrange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Formal_statement) you have
$$
\langle v,f(p)-f(q)\rangle = g(1)-g(0) = g'(s) = \langle v, Df_{sp+(1-s)q}(p-q)\rangle
$$
for some $s\in(0,1)$. Of course, $\xi=sp+(1-s)q\in[p,q]$.